# Disable double tap popup UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

There is a popup comes when double tap on `UITextView`. You can see it in below image. How can we disable this?

[image]

Comment: If you are just displaying text and not using it for user input then you can disable its user interaction, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Even if you use it for user input, then you can disable its multiple touches from Xib. Hope it helps.

Comment: @NewStackUser : User interaction is there. But they can't edit. simply can select.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
txtView.selectable = NO;
```

**Edited:**
Over ride this in your view controller to handle, Use this code where you have your `UITextfield`.

```
// Hide cut/copy/paste menu


-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
         UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
         if (menuController) {
            [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
         }
         return NO;
  }
```

For iOS 7 & later version you need to do like this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I can't do this because. i need the text is selectable.

Comment: @JansonThomas if you keep it selectable than popup will obviously open :)

Comment: there is no any other way to do it?